# What are Windows NT 10.3 and 10.5?

Tags: web-crawlers, user-agent

In my Apache logs, a few malicious scans were done by machines that identify their OS in their user agents as

```
Windows NT 10.3
Windows NT 10.5
```

Are these fictitious or were there at some point real Windows 10 releases with these numbers?

Comment: MS Windows Server used to be known as Windows NT back in the 1990's.  It's the core of what is now simply known as MS Windows and would include Windows desktop operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

As per [List of Microsoft Windows versions wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions) there are/were some Windows releases marked as `NT 10.0`, including Windows 10, Windows Server version 2004, Windows Server version 1909, Windows Server version 1903, Windows Server 2019 and Windows Server 2016.